# Find duplicate using insertion sort

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm, sorting, duplicates

```
def find_duplicate(arr):
    for i in range(1, len(arr)):
        cur = arr[i]
        j = i
        while j > 0 and arr[j - 1] > cur:
            arr[j] = arr[j - 1]
            j -= 1
        arr[j] = cur
        if arr[j-1] == cur:
            arr[j] = cur
            return f"This is the duplicate {cur}, {arr}"
        else:
            arr[j] = cur
    print("no dupes")
    return arr


print(find_duplicate([1,-5,3,4,-10,100,250,-325,100]))
```

When I add the 100 at the end of my array it gets sorted and the duplicate value is shown as 100 and the array is sorted properly, however when I add a negative number say -5 as the duplicate on the end, it does not sort the -5 yet some how understands that this number is the duplicate. What am I doing wrong?

please see the two arrays as inputs I've mentioned:

arr = [1,-5,3,4,-10,100,250,-325,100] <- 100 at end
arr = [1,-5,3,4,-10,100,250,-325,-5] <- -5 at end

```
print(find_duplicate([1,-5,3,4,-10,100,250,-325,100]))

print(find_duplicate([1,-5,3,4,-10,100,250,-325,-5]))


# OUTPUT BELOW:


This is the duplicate 100, [-325, -10, -5, 1, 3, 4, 100, 100, 250]
This is the duplicate -5, [-5, 1, 3, 4, -10, 100, 250, -325, -5]
```

Update:

when running this again

```
print(find_duplicate([1,-5,3,4,-10,100,250,-325,-5,10]))

this is the duplicate -5, [-325, -10, -5, -5, 1, 3, 4, 100, 250, 10]
```

Seems like it keeps just appending the numbers instead of sorting them after a duplicate is found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the logic right, except for the `return` statement inside the `if`

```py
def find_duplicate(arr):
    dup = None  # set this to none to act as flag
    for i in range(1, len(arr)):
        cur = arr[i]
        j = i
        while j > 0 and arr[j - 1] > cur:
            arr[j] = arr[j - 1]
            j -= 1
        arr[j] = cur
        if arr[j-1] == cur:
            arr[j] = cur
            dup = cur
        else:
            arr[j] = cur
    if dup is None:  # check if a duplicate was found
        print("no dupes")
        return arr
    else:
        return f"This is the duplicate {dup}, {arr}"


print(find_duplicate([1,-5,3,4,-10,100,250,-325,-5]))

print(find_duplicate([1,-5,3,4,-10,100,250,-325,100]))

print(find_duplicate([1,-5,3,4,-10,100,250,-325,-5,10]))
```

Output

```
This is the duplicate -5, [-325, -10, -5, -5, 1, 3, 4, 100, 250]
This is the duplicate 100, [-325, -10, -5, 1, 3, 4, 100, 100, 250]
This is the duplicate -5, [-325, -10, -5, -5, 1, 3, 4, 10, 100, 250]
```